# Import large db to aws RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to import my MySQL db of size around 25 GB to `aws rds`.How can i do this.
I tried using phpmyadmin of RDS. But my browser hang on.Also my AWS don't have public IP.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the quickest and easiest way is to make a backup, copy it to s3, and then tell RDS to import it from there:

> Amazon RDS supports importing MySQL databases by using backup files.
>   You can create a backup of your on-premises database, store it on
>   Amazon S3, and then restore the backup file onto a new Amazon RDS DB
>   instance running MySQL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DB size is only 25GB so you can go with mysqldump utility and uploaded the data into S3 but I suggest to go with Mydumper to take the backup because backup time can be reduced by using parallelization feature of it and restore from S3. another way is you can create a new ec2 instance in same region and account and upload backup there and restore it via MySQL or my loader(a tool used to restore mydumperbackup).